# swiftui combine can't fetch data

Tags: api, swiftui, combine

I write code, don't have an error in Xcode, but I can't get fetching data with combine, why? without combine this API working, with combine no) why? maybe I have mistake somewhere

```swift
class ModelView: ObservableObject {
  let baseURL = "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=taylor+swift&entity=song"
  private var task: AnyCancellable?
  @Published var result = [Result]()
  func fetchData() {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=taylor+swift&entity=song") else { 
      return 
    }
    task = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
      .map{$0.data}
      .decode(type: Response.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
      .map{$0.result}
      .replaceError(with: [Result]())
      .eraseToAnyPublisher()
      .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
      .assign(to: \ModelView.result, on: self)
  }
}
struct ContentView: View {
  @ObservedObject var model = ModelView()
  var body: some View {
    List {
      ForEach(model.result, id: \.self) { 
        i in VStack {
          Text(i.trackName)
        }
      }
    }.onAppear {
      self.model.fetchData()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your Result and Response?

Comment: struct Response: Codable {
    var results: [Result]
}

struct Result: Codable, Hashable {
    var trackId: Int
    var trackName: String
    var collectionName: String
}

Comment: Might need JSONDecoder

Comment: ... after some typos in the above code snapshot fixed all works. Xcode 12 / iOS 14.

Comment: no, not working) the code I write is right, but not fetch data

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code, its seems working fine. but im getting compile time error in your code, in this line

```
.map{$0.result}
```

I wonder how you can't. I had to change this line to

```
.map{$0.results}
```

Here is full code that i tried and working fine.

```
class ModelView: ObservableObject {
  let baseURL = "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=taylor+swift&entity=song"
  private var task: AnyCancellable?
  @Published var result = [Result]()

 func fetchData() {
       guard let url = URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=taylor+swift&entity=song") else {
    return
  }
  task = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
  .map{$0.data}
  .decode(type: Response.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
  .map{$0.results}
  .replaceError(with: [Result]())
  .eraseToAnyPublisher()
  .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
  .assign(to: \ModelView.result, on: self)
}
}

struct Response: Codable {
    var results: [Result]
}
struct Result: Codable, Hashable {
    var trackId: Int
    var trackName: String
    var collectionName: String
}
```

And make sure you added this key in plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

hope this'll help